# 2 DNS records point to the same address, but only 1 works

Tags: dns, cpanel

I am using Advanced Zone Editor in cPanel to have 2 addresses point to the same IP (my home ip). There is one (mc.tthread.com) that works flawlessly. On the other hand, i made a record yesterday (testing.tthread.com) to point to the same ip, and that doesn't seem to work. I realize that it takes a couple of hours for the DNS servers to update, but i believe 1 day is more than enough.

Both addresses share the same settings (Type 'A', TTL '14400').
Also, is there a way to minimize the time it would take the DNS servers to update their records?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: I can ping testing.tthread.com and get a reply from 79.172.252.60.  I see this is a different IP that mc.tthread.com.  Did you previously set up testing.tthread.com at a different IP?

Comment: You have not saved / made you change active - the IPAddress you get from ping is just the cpanel default *.tthread.com record

Comment: Yes, that ip is the cpanel deault. The settings are saved, they show up in the Zone File Records. What should i do?

Comment: Please help me. I really need some help. Any ideas? anything?

Comment: If you only have access to cPanel, have you tried to delete the A record and create it again? If you have access to WHM, you can check your zone in WHM -> Edit DNS Zone and make sure that you update your SOA record as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to minimize the downtime overall but if this is for some testing/development then what you can do is to use DNS HOSTS hack & override the IP given by your DNS server to that of your need on your workstation.

DNS HOSTS hack file is at: /etc/hosts (Linux) C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (Windows)

Using Google's DNS server will may work sometimes too.

You can use whatsmydns to have a track of DNS propagation: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/testing.tthread.com